# C# Unable to Get HTTP Return Codes via HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, httpresponsemessage

I’m getting an error in VS trying to check the Return Code of a method that builds and post data via an API.
The line that is generating the error is:

```
if (BuildApi(MyGlobals.data5, MyGlobals.data1, FQAN, MyGlobals.data4) == MyGlobals.ReturnCode)
```

The error is:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Task<string'>' and 'string'

My goal is to pass those parameters (data1, data5, etc) to the `BuildApi()` method and then post that data via an API call.

When the data is successfully posted, I should get a Return Code of 200 or a Return Code of 400 if an error occurred (according to the API developer). 
The `BuildApi()` method should return either a 200 or 400 back to the condition statement.
Is the `BuildApi()` method formatted correctly to return the Return Code and if so, what’s wrong with that “if” statement?

Full Code:

```
static class MyGlobals
{
    public static XmlDocument XmlAccounts = new XmlDocument();
    public static XmlNode XmlRoot;
    public static string data1 { get; set; }
    public static string data2 { get; set; }
    public static string data3 { get; set; }
    public static string data4 { get; set; }
    public static string data5 { get; set; }
    public static string ReturnCode { get; set; }

}

static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SqlConnection ObjConn = new SqlConnection();
    string ConnectMe = @"

            Data Source             =SERVER;
            Database                =DATABASE1;
            User ID                 =USER;
            Pwd                     =PASS;
            Connection Timeout      =700

        ";



    // Open Connection
    ObjConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectMe);
    ObjConn.Open();

    // Call methods based on the required tool
    SR_Provisioning(ObjConn);
    
}

static public void SR_Provisioning(SqlConnection ObjConn)
{
    Get = @"

        SELECT
            data1,
            data2,
            data3,
            data4,
            data5

        FROM
            table
    ";



    ObjAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(Get, ObjConn);
    ObjAdp.Fill(OutputTable); 

    foreach (DataRow OutputRow in OutputTable.Rows)

    {

        //Initalize FQAN

        string FQAN = "";



        // Convert query output to variables

        MyGlobals.data1 = OutputRow[0].ToString();
        MyGlobals.data2 = OutputRow[1].ToString();
        MyGlobals.data3 = OutputRow[2].ToString();
        MyGlobals.data4 = OutputRow[3].ToString();
        MyGlobals.data5 = OutputRow[4].ToString();

        // Instantiate new objects

        strFunctions MyStr = new strFunctions();
        wshWin32API win32api = new wshWin32API();

        // Convert server to FQDN for accessibility ease
        string FQDN = getFQDN(MyGlobals.data1, ObjConn);

        // Perform action based on Tranaction_Type
        switch (MyGlobals.data5)

        {
            case "Add":
                if (MyGlobals.data2 == "LOCAL")
                {
                    // Create local ID first
                    try
                    {
                        FQAN = MyGlobals.data1 + "\\" + MyGlobals.data3;
                        // Check the return code to determine how to log the results

                        if (BuildApi(MyGlobals.data5, MyGlobals.data1, FQAN, MyGlobals.data4) == MyGlobals.ReturnCode)

                        {
                            switch (MyGlobals.ReturnCode)
                            /*
                                Return Codes
                                200 (Created)
                                400(Expectation Failed)
                            */

                            {
                                case "200":
                                    // Do something
                                    AllIsGood();
                                    break;

                                case "400":
                                    // Do something else
                                    AllIsBad();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        // Handle error and update transaction record
                        Update_Row();
                    }
                }
}


static async Task<string> BuildApi(string data5, string data1, string FQAN, string data4)

{
    try
    {
        UriBuilder baseUri = new UriBuilder("https://pwmfunction001.azurewebsites.net/api/VMGroupMemberModify01?code=T753ljF4jwXZXzmotCnnrBdV7Mrbqvcd3ibazRb92ZoBfJADuCpq5w==-Headers@{Metadata=true}-Body@{");

        // Create the query string
        string queryToAppend = "DATA5=" + data5 + ";DATA1=" + data1 + ";FQAN=" + FQAN + ";data4=" + data4 + "}";

        if (baseUri.Query != null && baseUri.Query.Length > 1)
        {
            baseUri.Query = baseUri.Query.Substring(1) + ";" + queryToAppend;
        }
        else
        {
            // Check this
            baseUri.Query = queryToAppend;
        }

        string httpResponseBody = "";
        
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        
        var content = new StringContent(client.ToString());
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(baseUri.ToString(), content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            httpResponseBody = "200";
            return httpResponseBody;
        }
        else
        {
            httpResponseBody = "400";
            return httpResponseBody;
        }
    }
    catch(HttpRequestException err)
    {
        throw err;
    }  

}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BuildApi function is async so you need to await it in your code:

```
if (await BuildApi(MyGlobals.data5, MyGlobals.data1, FQAN, MyGlobals.data4) == MyGlobals.ReturnCode)
```

UPDATE:

If you can't run it async then you need the result:

```
if (BuildApi(MyGlobals.data5, MyGlobals.data1, FQAN, MyGlobals.data4).Result == MyGlobals.ReturnCode)
```

However, I would try in the first instance to make your calling method async

Comment: But then the method calling `BuildApi` is not async, so that won't work as is.

Comment: Thanks Guys @GlynnHurrell and @EtennedeMartel! The updated solution cleared the error in VS. I'll test once the API is ready. One question - Does the BuildApi() method look solid to you? This is my very first time posting to an API.

Comment: Obviously it depends on whether you have any control over the API but no not really. You are trying to post to an API but you're passing data via the query string! Whilst it will work, you should definitely avoid it! You should instead be passing data in the request body - You're half way there with new StringContent(...), you just want to model your data and then convert it to a JSON string.